# Getting error while reading the file content using Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to read the file content using `URL` and return that the content as response in html format but getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/rework/Nuclear/RFI/secure/plant/views.py", line 217, in view_reactor
    pers = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['id'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 57, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
KeyError: u'id'
```

I am providing my code below:

```
site = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    my_list = []
    my_list.extend(['home', 'view_reactor'])
    if request.GET.get('file') is not None and request.GET.get('file') != '':
        file = request.GET.get('file')
        if file in my_list:
            full_path = site+file
            response = urllib.urlopen(full_path)
            lines = response.readlines()
            return HttpResponse(content=lines, content_type="text/html")
        else:
            return render(request, 'plant/home.html', {'count': 1})
    else:
        return render(request, 'plant/home.html', {'count': 1})


def view_reactor(request):
    """ This function for to get serch screen. """

    pers = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['id'])
    root = []
    user_name = pers.uname
    count = 1
    root.append(
        {'username': user_name,
         'count': count
         })
    return render(request, 'plant/view_reactor.html',
                  {'user': root, 'count': 1})
```

Here I am passing the the value in query string like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/createfile/?file=view_reactor` and finally I need the response of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_reactor` page in html format. But in my code I am getting this error.

Comment: Share the complete stack trace

Comment: @arjun27 : I pasted my complete stack trace with required code.

Comment: your session dict does contains id "pk=request.session['id']"

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that there is no `id` key in your `session` dictionary. In the following line:

```
pers = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['id'])
```

And to me it looks redundant to get a user like this. You should be able to get a user simply by doing this:

```
pers = request.user
```

Provided that you have auth middleware installed.

Second option (not tested though):

```
pers = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
```

Comment: I did as per you but its throwing this `AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'uname'
` error.

Comment: @satya it means that the user was not authenticated before using this view. You should authenticate him when he logs in.

Comment: @satya please see the second option in my updated answer

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_reactor` has the id in session because I can open this directly but here i am passing the same in query string and also `content_type="text/plain"` is working fine.

Comment: No, its throwing this error `Exception Value:  

u'_auth_user_id'` . Actually after login i am setting the ID in session.

Comment: @satya well, it is definitely not there. Please do `print(session)` and post the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154100/discussion-between-satya-and-jahongir-rahmonov).